# Какие практические преимущества Базы Данных Яндекс над PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, yandex-database, ydb

Есть проект на Node.js. до 100000 в месяц нагрузка сайта, в котором есть таблицы БД профилей, покупок тарифных пакетов, результатов неких вычислений, записей секции блога, таблицы рассылок и другое.

Важно, что бы было автомасштабирование ресурсов, отказоустойчивость на случай резкого роста нагрузки (есть в ЯБД).